# How to Automatically Delete MongoDB Data After a Certain Time Using Mongoose in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I created a time-series collection using MongoDB database, and I expected the data to be automatically deleted after 2 minutes, but it did not happen. I checked the database and found that the data still exists.

I created a `time-series` collection using MongoDB database and I need to delete the data in the `nonce` field after 2 minutes. I created it using MongoDB Compass, and my parameters are as follows:

[image]

However, when I insert data using mongoose in node.js, the data is not deleted after 2 minutes.

Here is the code I am using:

```js
const nonceSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    nonce: String,
    ts: Date,
})

const nonceModel = mongoose.model('nonce', nonceSchema,'nonce');

await nonceModel.create({
        nonce: nonce,
        ts: new Date(),
    });
```

This code correctly inserts data, but the data is not automatically deleted.

```json
[{
  "ts": {
    "$date": "2023-04-29T06:28:21.345Z"
  },
  "nonce": "R8tYOm15zEu1BupI",
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "644cb90554447c607a4a5a37"
  },
  "__v": 0
},{
  "ts": {
    "$date": "2023-04-29T06:28:47.098Z"
  },
  "nonce": "fFHGD8h6LwUDFIWo",
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "644cb91f54447c607a4a5a3b"
  },
  "__v": 0
}]
```

What should I do? Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution: Create `nonce` as a regular collection instead of a `time series` and add the following code to the JavaScript:

```
const nonceSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    nonce: String,
    ts: Date,
})
// add this code
nonceSchema.index({ ts: 1 }, { expireAfterSeconds: 120 });
const nonceModel = mongoose.model('nonce', nonceSchema,'nonce');

await nonceModel.create({
        nonce: nonce,
        ts: new Date(),
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the TTL index before you insert data into the collection. If you create the TTL index after inserting data, the existing data will not be deleted automatically based on the TTL index.